# Repeated data in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-office

I have several records and fields in Microsoft Access. One of the fields named `Address` contains repeated values like so,

```
Address

234 Avenue 
123 Street 
234 Avenue 
234 Avenue
```

I want only one `234 Avenue` to be displayed. All others should be deleted. What is the simplest way of doing this?

**UPDATE 1**

I found all the values that are repeated in the `Address` field. I also found the number of times they are being repeated. I just need to figure out how to delete these values so that there are no duplicates. This is the query I used:

```
SELECT First(Addresses.[ADDRESS]) AS [ADDRESS Field], Count(Addresses.[ADDRESS]) AS NumberOfDups
FROM Addresses
GROUP BY Addresses.[ADDRESS]
HAVING (((Count(Addresses.[ADDRESS]))>1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a make table query to extract data from your original table and delete the original once you have a new table with unique address.

Use the following sql to create the new table

```
SELECT distinct ADDRESS INTO Addresses2 FROM Addresses
```

Running it should create a new table called Addresses2 with unique. Once you are happy with it delete Addresses and then rename  Addresses2.

I strongly suggest that you start using tbl in front of your table names and fld for your field names it will make your codes and sql much easier to read.

Comment: +1 for the solution, but the "fld" prefix isn't necessary unless you're using reserved words as your field names (like "Date", "Name", etc...).

Comment: I'd still recommend using prefix because you will eventually use data from the field to populate controls in your form. When looking a code it is useful to be able to quickly know if the code is referring to the data "fldDate" or the textbox containing the data txtDate.